# iOS 11.2 NFC-Tag random UID

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

With iOS 11.2 i can´t read the real uid from tag. I can read a id from "NFCNDEFReaderSession" but this id is change with every scan.

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {

    var uid: String = ""
    if(session.value(forKey: "_foundTags") != nil) {

        let foundTags : NSArray = session.value(forKey: "_foundTags") as! NSArray
        if(foundTags.count > 0) {

            let tag : NSObject = foundTags.firstObject  as! NSObject;
            if(tag.value(forKey: "_UID") != nil) {
```

I need the real UID from the NFC-Tag. Have somebody a idea to get the uid from a nfc-tag. With iOS 11.0 was it possible to read this information.

Comment: I don't believe that you can. You can only get the NDEF data.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to iOS 11.2.1 it was possible by reading the "_tagID" from the foundTags Array of the Session. But after the update it only returns nil.
Our company has the same issue and we are thinking about talking to apple about this problem, so it was possible, but it was also a private API call, which is not allowed due to apple guidelines. Our app got restricted because of that, and we removed nfc reading from it, to get our updates through.

Now it seems they simply deleted the value from the foundTags Array of the Session. I see no technical reason why it should not be possible. It is maybe a question of IT security.
Hopefully apple responds to that and we will know more about the reasons next year.

Comment: Hey, do you found any solution on this. I am able to access NFC data. but still getting _tagId nil.